# When would you use "kommen", "ankommen", or "eintreffen"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, verb

I was talking with my partner about when he would be arriving home and when our guest would be arriving. I didn't know the word for "arrive" and Google translate didn't provide much enlightenment. I settled for "Wann wirst du zu Hause gekommen?" and "Sie wird um 6:00 ankommen" but I have no idea why.

Comment: I think Google translate gets it just fine... https://translate.google.de/#auto/de/when%20will%20you%20arrive%20at%20home%3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ankommen vs Eintreffen

There is a difference between `ankommen` and `eintreffen`.
The former one is much more generic, you can also "ankommen/arrive" at a certain state of mind. If the journey was stressful and long, the host will often say to the `eintreffenden (arriving)` guests:

> "Kommt (or formal: Kommen Sie) erst mal an!"

in the sense of taking off the jacket and shoes, drop your luggage etc. before starting the dinner or other activities.

`Eintreffen` is (always?) the very short moment of `arrive at a location/scene`.

`Ankommen` can be used synonymously, but is also an activity on its own.

---

### Ankommen vs Kommen

In situations like the one that you described (arriving at home at a certain time) it doesn't matter which one you use.
In other situation `ankommen` again means the arrival and `kommen` can mean the whole travel, too.

For instance, you have to cancel an appointment today:

> Ich komme heute nicht mehr.  / I won't visit (you) today.

For instance, you will be arriving tomorrow instead of today, because you missed the last leg of your flight:

> Ich komme heute nicht mehr **an**. / I won't be arriving today.

Answer (score 3):

> Wann wirst du zu Hause ankommen?

is just fine for asking someone when the person will arrive at his/her home.

If you live with your partner, you can also say

> Wann wirst du nach Hause kommen?

or a bit more informal

> Wann wirst du heimkommen?

to ask her when she will come home.

> Wann wirst du zu Hause eintreffen?

is fine, but I would consider it a bit too formal for asking your partner.

> Sie wird um 6 Uhr heimkommen.
>   Sie wird um 6 Uhr nach Hause kommen.
>   Sie wird um 6 Uhr (zu Hause) ankommen.
>   Sie wird um 6 Uhr (zu Hause) eintreffen.

are all fine as statements (sorted from informal to formal).

Answer (score 1):

"ankommen" and "eintreffen" are quite the same in the meaning of arriving at a destination or place. So both are fine with both sentences:

> Wann wirst du zu Hause ankommen? 
> Wann wirst du zu Hause
>   eintreffen? 
> Sie wird um 6:00 Uhr ankommen. 
> Sie wird um 6:00
>   Uhr eintreffen.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the meanings of the three German words in English:

kommen - come
ankommen - arrive
eintreffen - entering a house, a room. etc.

Comment: I don't agree with "eintreffen" being only for entering. People eintreffen at Unglücksorten every day